# Amount of unique elements from an Array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

**This is homework**

I just want hints on what the error is.
I'm trying to compare each element of the array with each other and return the number of unique elements. I am getting an error by one?
Can someone help me finding what the error is?

```
public static int numUnique (double[] list) {
    int index = 1;
    int result = 0;
    if(list.length == 0){return 0;}

    while(index < list.length) {
        if(list[index] != list[index - 1]) {
            result = result + 1;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Failed numUnique([11]): Expecting (1) Actual (0)

Failed numUnique([11 11 11 11]): Expecting (1) Actual (0)

Failed numUnique([11 21 31 41]): Expecting (4) Actual (3)

Failed numUnique([11 11 11 21 31 31 31 31 41]): Expecting (4) Actual (3)

Failed numUnique([11 21 21 21 31 41 41 41 41]): Expecting (4) Actual (3)

Failed numUnique([11 11 21 21 21 31 31 41 41 41 41]): Expecting (4) Actual (3)
```

Comment: why not simply initialize `result` with 1 instead if 0?

Comment: Oh it worked! But why?

Comment: Because you are basically counting the transition between different values, the number of transitions is always one lower than the number of different values.

Answer (score 1):

By setting the initial value of `index` to 1 your loop is skipping the 0 element, since you can guarantee that it is unique (because you haven't looked at any elements yet). Since that's the case, you should initialize `result` to 1 as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It makes sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is flawed, you are only comparing each element with the one right before and you are counting how many times they differ.

It seems to work in your example because all the duplicates are next to each other, but your description does not specify that is always the case.

You want to compare each element with all the other elements **before** and count how many times they are unique:

```
int uniques = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < list.length ; i++) {
    boolean found = false;
    for(int j = 0 ; j < i ; j++) {
        if(list[i] == list[j]) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    uniques += found ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: A better solution would be to sort the array upfront so you have a O(n) instead of O(n^2) algorithm.

Comment: It would be O(n log n) counting the sort. But I am trying to respect the strategy of the OP: "I'm trying to compare each element of the array with each other and return the number of unique elements."

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**CODE:**

```
public class uniqueElements {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        double[] list = new double[8];
        list[0] = 1.1;
        list[1] = 2.4;
        list[2] = 3.5;
        list[3] = 1.1;
        list[4] = 2.4;
        list[5] = 2.4;
        list[6] = 3.3;
        list[7] = 3.5;
        System.out.println(numUnique(list));
    }

    public static int numUnique (double[] list) {
        int numUniqueCounter = 0;
        A: 
            for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
                double currentNumber = list[i];         
                for(int j=i+1;j<list.length;j++){
                    if(list[j] == currentNumber){                               
                        continue A;                     
                    }
                }               
                numUniqueCounter++;
            }
        return numUniqueCounter;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead, efficient and with single pass you can determine unique elements

```
public static int numUnique(double[] list) {
        Set<Double> uniqueSet = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            uniqueSet.add(list[i]);
        }
        return uniqueSet.size();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot resist:

```
   public static int numUnique (Double[] list) {
    return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(list)).size();
   }
```

Not the change from double[] to Double[].

You should try to avoid looping manually as much as possible. Loops are buggy, as you are finding out. Learn to use the collections.

Comment: Well... I can't use any collections! This is a only method homework. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: ouch. Then you are doomed do doing a double loop. The code in your question only compares to the previous element. You need to check every element.